# How can I get Adobe Lightroom to automatically crop two different 5x7 photos to fit on one 8.5x11 sheet?

Tags: lightroom, printing

When using the standard Lightroom templates for printing I can select the Zoom to Fill option so the photos will get cropped to the appropriate size BUT I can not select 2 different 5x7 photos on the same 8.5 x 11 sheet.

So I created a user template with 2 separate 5x7 photos BUT it appears that on custom user templates there is no way to have the photos Zoom to Fill.  The Zoom to Fill choice under Image Settings doesn't even show up as a choice on user templates.

Perhaps there is another way to go about this?  I was trying to avoid having to manually crop each individual photo to fit the desired print size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the *contact sheet* option?

- In layout style click on *Single image/Contact Sheet*
- Click *zoom to fill*
- I then jumped to *Page grid*. 2 rows 1 column
- Changed the settings at *cell size* to 5"x7"
- **Optional** Then go back to *Margins* to position on page

By doing it this way it will constrain to 5x7 and you can position it how you want on the page

Comment: Sweet that worked great, I hadn't thought of using the contact sheet.  I did have to remember to uncheck the Photo Info box to not print the filename as part of the photo too.

Answer (score 2):

The printing pane turns out to be pretty easy once you get the hang of the basics.

Either get one of the existing templates, or create a new one and delete everything off of the page (highlight each element and then delete).

Toggle the filmstrip on the bottom of the screen and select one of the photos you want and drag it onto the canvas.  It should show up in a new box that you can move and resize.  Holding shift (to lock the aspect ratio), resize the image and move it around the page until it is where you want it.

Repeat for the second image.

There are selectors for inner stroke and photo border that you can adjust as you like to get your desired look.

Comment: That describes how to resize the pictures but I am trying to crop photos since their aspect ratio was different than the print aspect ratio, aka the zoom to fill option.

Comment: When I follow those steps, the pictures in the print page have the Zoom To Fill option selected.  Are you in LR3 or LR2?

Comment: LR3, I seem to only get the Zoom To Fill option when the Layout Style is Picture Package, and when it's Picture Package I can only put the same photo on the page.  If I change the Layout Style to Custom Package then I can put 2 pictures on like you describe but the Zoom To Fill check box disappears.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I was testing with two similar looking pictures and didn't realize they were actually the same shot.